# Arduino Controlling through C#

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-leonardo

i would like to measure some signals from arduino and send it to a pc using USART and display the results in a c# winform application. Does anyone have such a project example ?
Besides, i want to send the data in live time mode, each values should be directly transmitted and then the second measurement ( sample rate 100 kHz )
Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you sure you can support that sample rate with your communications?

Comment: The maximum sampling rate for analog signals is 10 kHz at default 10 bit resolution. Digital should be ok. The USB bus is nominally 12 MBit/s. Assuming 1-byte data size, you would probably have to send the data in 64 byte bursts(max packet size) if you want a chance of having eneough bandwidth since there is also overhead. Whether possible would depend on the Leonardo USB implementation and possibly also hardware/software on the PC.

Comment: User2973, you should post your comment as an answer, and then the OP should accept it. (Excellent, through treatment of the question. Voted.)

Comment: ok, if we assume with 5 KHz samle rate, do you can any suggestion for c# PC program to control the board ?

Comment: This question was never specific enough for the rules of this site, and has clearly been abandoned for over a year.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing the point here or wouldn't the C# just have to open a Serial connection to the board and read and write to that to control the program running on the Arduino?
Yes the board is connected by USB, but that's only so it can open a serial connection.
To be honest I don't think you will be able to sample at that speed, you might be better looking at ICs that directly interface with GPIO and RS232/USB.